# Java Array of Enum Class implementing an interface accepts other Enums not implementing Interfaces as well

Tags: java, arrays, enums, interface, extend

I have java enums that implement a Direction interface as below.

```
public enum AdvanceDirection implements Direction {....}

public enum BasicDirection implements Direction {....}
```

I also have an enum NonDirection that doesn't implements Direction as below

```
public enum NonDirection {....}
```

I have a function that should only return an Array of Enum classes that implements Direction as below

```
public static <T extends Enum<T> & Direction> Class<T>[] getDirections() {
  return new Class[]{AdvanceDirection.class, BasicDirection.class, NonDirection.class};
}
```

But if I add NonDirection.class to this Array, it still returns it without any errors. How can I make sure that  getDirections() method only returns array of Enums that implements Direction Interface ?

Usage example

```
public static void printDirections() {
  for (Class c: getDirections()) {
    System.out.println(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Arrays don't work well with generics. You should instead use a `List` anyway.

Comment: Why not just return `Direction[]`? Why so adamant that is needs to be an `enum`?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes OP's example returns an array of classes. A suggestion to return an array of objects of type `Direction` makes no sense at all.

Comment: No, just returning classes makes no sense at all, especially if the method is called `getDirections`.

Comment: Please ignore the method name getDirections(). I have used it as an example. Think of getDirections() a Spring bean configuration that returns an array of Enums that implements Direction Interface.

Answer (score 1):

You have hit a known limitation of the use of generics in Java. The language designers (sensibly IMO) decided to use type erasure to limit the impact of the introduction of generics on the runtime engine. However this limits some uses of generics that would otherwise seem natural.

Your options are:

1. use a collection instead of an array. This would be my recommendation: there's really no advantage to arrays in the case you've given and will allow tighter type checking at compile time.
2. use reflection to test the class's inheritance at runtime and throw an exception.

I realise your examples is contrived for the purpose of asking the question (for which I commend you) but the use of generics and `Class` objects you've shown seems quite unusual. If you give more details on what you are trying to achieve there could well be a more natural solution within Java.

Comment: The getDirections() method can be assumed as Spring Bean config that returns hat returns an array of Enums that implements Direction Interface.